# error in socket io request by angular 8 and sailsJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, angular8

Im new at socket.io and in Angular I made a socket request forward to sailsJS (backend) but after requesting i get the following error:

Sails responded with:  Error: The 2-ary usage of `res.json()` is no longer supported in Express 4/Sails v1.  Please use `res.status(statusCode).json(body)` instead.

in angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import * as sailsIOClient from 'sails.io.js';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketIoService {
  private socket = sailsIOClient(io);
  constructor() {
    this.socket.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
  }

  sendRequest() {
    console.log('call sokcet')
    this.socket.socket.get('/socket', (resData) => {
      console.log('Sails responded with: ', resData);
    });
  }
}
```

in sails js i have below config and code: 
in routes.js:

```
'get /socket': 'TaskController.Index',
```

in TaskController.js:

```
module.exports = {
  Index: function (req, res) {
    console.log('in sails socket', req.isSocket);
    if( !req.isSocket) {
      return res.badRequest();
    }
    sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'task');
    sails.sockets.broadcast('task', 'list');
    // sails.sockets.blast('task', 'entry');
    return res.ok();
  }
}
```

in socket.js:

```
transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue by the changing the "return code" in token Authorized function:
resolved code:

```
return res.status(401).json({err: 'No Authorization header was found'});
```

old code (throw error):

```
 return res.json(401, {err: 'No Authorization header was found'});
```